# math.js + MathJax: show fraction as inline or slash for units like m/s or mi/h

Tags: mathjax, math.js

Need help with math.js and LaTeX using MathJax.

For example, at the moment:
`\frac{140.8~\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}}`

Will result to: [image]

Which is not what I want.

I want to force it to use slash (eg: 140.8 m/s) or display as 140.8 ms^(-1).

I'm new in using math.js with MathJax.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So I found out about `macros`, so created one to replace `\frac` with `\flatfrac`.

```
window.MathJax = {
  loader: {load: ['[tex]/physics']},
  tex: {
        packages: {'[+]': ['physics']},
        macros: {
            frac: "\\flatfrac"
        }
    }
};
```

Not sure this is the best thing or correct usage, but it works!